# Register and Resolving Dependencies on Request Based on Param (Autofac WEB API)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an Application with autofac dependency injection and I wanted to use a specific dll extension based on the parameter I have on the request.

Here's my global.asax where I initialize autofac.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
containerBuilder.RegisterModule<ExModule>();            

var container = containerBuilder.Build();

container.Resolve<IArtigoErp>();
```

Here's the autofac module where I load register my DLL's

```
public class ExModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //Load DLL1 from folder and register it
        RegistaDepedencias<IArtigoErp>(builder, "DLL1");

        //Load DLL2 from folder and register it
        RegistaDepedencias<IArtigoErp>(builder, "DLL2");

        
    }

    private void RegistaDepedencias<T>(ContainerBuilder builder, string NomeDll)
    {
        RegisterDep<T>(GetEnumerableTypes<T>(NomeDll), builder);
    }

    private void RegisterDep<T>(IEnumerable<Type> types, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var t in types)
        {
            builder.RegisterType(t).As<T>();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetEnumerableTypes<T>(string NomeDll)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "Engine"))
            .Where(x => x.Contains(NomeDll) && x.EndsWith(NomeDll +".dll"))
            .Select(x => Assembly.LoadFrom(x))
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass));
    }
}
```

Both my DLL's have a class that extend from IArtigoErp.

So the ideia is, based on the parameter I get on my request, I want to run the method in either DLL1 or DLL2.
Example:

```
if(param == 1)
   _artigoErp.GetLista(); // In DLL1
if(param == 2)
   _artigoErp.GetLista(); // In DLL2
```

EDIT 1:

The parameter comes from the post method as it follows (Guid IdLoja)

```
public class ArtigoController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IArtigoErp _artigoErp;
    private readonly IArtigoLoja _artigoLoja;

    public ArtigoController(IArtigoErp artigoErp, IArtigoLoja artigoLoja)
    {
        _artigoErp = artigoErp;
        _artigoLoja = artigoLoja;
    }

    [Route("PostArtigos")]
    public CallResponse PostArtigos([FromBody] Guid IdLoja)
    {
    }
}
```

I guess we can also process this in the begin_request method in global.asax

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is param coming from? Is this runtime information or information that is set in the config file? Is it loaded from the database, or posted from a browser? Can you show the relevant code that uses this `param`?

Comment: Hello Steven. Thanks for helping. I've updated the post with what you asked. Based on the parameter IdLoja I need to tell autofac to use DLL1 or DLL2.

Comment: The example code shows the same object - _artigoErp - with two different methods that both have the same name but are somehow in two different assemblies? How would that even compile?

Comment: It compiles. The thing is, when you resolve multiple DLL with the same assembly, autofac always "uses" the last resolved